# php to silverlight base64 encode/decode

Tags: php, silverlight, base64

My question is quite similar with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257462/c-to-php-base64-encode-decode).
But it is php to silverlight.

my php code (server encode):

```
$str = 'This is the string';
$encoded = base64_encode($str);
```

How could I achieved the decoded string in Silverlight 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has actually nothing to do with PHP, just about decoding base64 strings in Silverlight - which, if a quick Google search is to be believed, happens like this:

```
byte[] content = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
```