# Compatible way of encoding / decoding image for php, java and c#

Tags: c#, java, php, .net

Is there a way to encode and decode base64 image string that would be cross compatible for multiple language? I'm looking at .NET, Java and PHP. If not are there other work arounds?

Comment: base64 is base64. It is the same across all languages.

Comment: @Oded: I heard that php decode does not work with C# encoding of base64 on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257462/c-sharp-to-php-base64-encode-decode

Comment: The link seems to discuss issues with base64 being passed through on the URL.

Comment: @Oded: Are there other ways to share images to different languages aside from base 64 string?

Comment: @Oded: wouldn't it be difficult if dealing with a lot of images?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4573/discussion-between-corbee-and-oded)

Comment: Seeing as you don't explain exactly what you need to achive, I can't really tell.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few variants of base64 (basically the same, but small changes). See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table

Just pick one and have them all use it.

It's easy enough to use search/replace to change the char 62 and 63 if necessary.